# Show that the equation $b(z+\bar z)+\bar b(\bar z-z)+a=0$ represents two straight lines in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Q**:if $a$ is real, $b=p+iq,z=x+iy$ and $\bar b=p-iq,\bar z=x-iy$ then show that the equation $b(z+\bar z)+\bar b(\bar z-z)+a=0$ represents two straight lines in the complex plane.
**My approach**:Simplify the equation i get,\begin{align}b(z+\bar z)+\bar b(\bar z-z)+a & =0 \\
 (p+iq)(x+iy+x-iy)+(p-iq)(x-iy-x-iy)+a & =0 \\
(2xp-2yq+a)+i(2xq-2py) & =0
\end{align}
But now i get stuck because i don't know how to show that it represent two straight lines. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Equate the real & the imaginary parts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Straight Line Equation in Complex Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934323/straight-line-equation-in-complex-plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have yielded :

$$(2xp-2yq+a)+i(2xq-2py)  =0$$

Now, for a complex expression $x_1 + y_1 i$ to be equal to zero, both imaginary and real parts must be equal to zero. Thus :

$$2xp-2yq+a = 0 \implies y = \frac{p}{q}x + \frac{a}{2q}$$

$$2xq - 2py = 0 \implies y = \frac{q}{p}x$$

which are both equations of straight lines, as $p,q,a$ are constants $ \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

1. If $A$ and $B$ are real, $A+Bi=0$ if and only if $A=B=0$.
2. $2xp-2yq+a$ and $2xq-2py$ are real.